# How to get the Physical address of a C pointer as a value?

Tags: c, pointers

in my system,

```
sizeof(void*) = 8 bytes
```

size of all  pointer types is 8 bytes.

I have this struct

```
struct element{void* value};
```

so this struct is jus a pointer value of 8 bytes.

since all type of pointers have 8 bytes, I should be able to just assign the physical address of any type of variable to this void* value

also,

```
sizeof(double) = 8 bytes;
```

question is how do I obtain the physical address of any pointer as a double value and then assign this value to any other 8 byte pointer.

so say,

```
int i;
int *p = &i;
struct element e;
double phy_address = ?? // the 8 byte value of p (when we print it as %d)

/*now copy this 8 byte phy_address to 8 byte void pointer e.value. */
```

Is it possible to typecast it as int* or any other pointer type? its jus an address...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162146/discussion-on-question-by-nelson-aka-spooky-how-to-get-the-physical-address-of-a).

Comment: You may just try `memcpy (&phy_address, &element.value, sizeof (void*))`. But this is weird.

Comment: 1: 'physical address' is wrong word for it. Virtual address or logical address is correct.
2. I understand Double is not good choice of data type here. What about just an array of bytes?  How do I convert to array of 8 bytes - the quickest way possible without much intermediate conversion.

Answer (score 1):

On most systems there is an integer type that is the same size as a `void *`. Usually this type is `int` or `long int` or `long long int`. Most compilers will provide the type, `intptr_t` (and its unsigned cousin `uintptr_t`), that is a typedef of one of these types. I think people prefer to use `uintptr_t` because negative address values usually don't make sense. Anyway you should probably use this type instead of double.

Remember that `uintptr_t` is just one of the regular integer types, so once you get the pointer value into a variable of this type, you can do any integer arithmetic you like. As for how to get the pointer value into a uintptr_t, see this question/answer, [Converting a non-`void` pointer to `uintptr_t` and vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291377/converting-a-non-void-pointer-to-uintptr-t-and-vice-versa).

Comment: Ty Ok. Plz also tell me  What  is the most direct way of knowing the allowed range of locations for any process of my program.Plz tell me  this

Comment: @NelsonakaSpOOKY: This is worth another question.

Answer (score 0):

> I use= these values can be used as unique identifier in a table.

OK. This information is necessary because there is no possibility to convert a pointer into a floating-point number with any meaningful value; the floating-point number will have a meaningless value in any way.

There are two possibilities to convert a pointer to a (meaningless) floating-point value but in both cases you are **not guaranteed** that two floating-point numbers are unique for two different pointers!

**Possibility 1:**

Convert the pointer to an integer and the integer to floating-point:

```
phy_address = (double)(uintptr_t)p;
```

However as Weather Vane already mentioned in his comment `double` values have a limited precision.

The integer values (addresses) 12345678901234567**80** and 12345678901234567**90** would **both** be rounded to 12345678901234567**68**.0.

**Possibility 2:**

Because both `double` and pointers are 64 bits wide you could generate a floating-point number that has the same bits as the pointer:

```
union {
    void *p;
    double d;
} u;
    ...
u.p = p;
phy_address = u.d;
```

However there are numbers (for example the `0`) which have two different representations in the `double` data type. This means that there are two different combinations of bits (and therefore two different addresses) that will generate the same number.

For this reason there **cannot** be any method to convert a 64-bit value into a `double` value resulting in an unique `double` value: The data type `double` has less than 2^64 different values!

And it is even worse:

There are special values - so called "NaN" values. And there are a lot of them!

I just did the following test:

```
// Write a "NaN" value to a
...
b = a;
if(a == b) puts("equal");
if(a != b) puts("not equal");
// Check if a and b still contain the same value
...
```

... and I get the result "not equal" although the check at the end says that `a` and `b` still contain the same value!

Depending on your environment some NaN values (so-called "signalling NaN" values) might even cause your program to crash!

**Conclusion**

Personally I would **never** use floating-point data types as "unique identifier".

In your case I would directly use `void *` as "unique identifier". If this is not possible I would use some 64-bit integer data type as "Stuart" already suggested in his answer.

Comment: Thanks, I don't really want it as a double. I jus want the 8 bytes as they are.